# Ansible: conflicting action statements: group, tags

Tags: tags, ansible

I have following code in on of roles:

```
- name: Create user group
  group: name={{ user.group }} state=present
  tags:
    - user
```

When I run `ansible-playbook -i localhost --ask-become-pass playbook.yml` I catch an error:

```
ERROR! conflicting action statements: group, tags

The error appears to have been in '/home/user/spark/roles/base/tasks/main.yml': line 12, column 3, but may
be elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.

The offending line appears to be:


- name: Create user group
  ^ here

...

exception type: <class 'ansible.errors.AnsibleParserError'>
exception: conflicting action statements: group, tags

...
```

Full error log: https://www.pastiebin.com/59cb4faf9ae35

If I remove `tags` it runs without error.

It was compnow it is exception: unexpected parameter type in action:  after I leave only name and tags. Full error log: pastiebin.com/59cb5b2996a10letely ok all the time but now it works like this without any identifiable reason. I tried to use previous working version of playbook (through git checkout ) but error exists anyway :(

I would be grateful for any hint on this.

P.S. I have fork of [ansible playbook for Archlinux machine](https://github.com/pigmonkey/spark).
P.P.S.

```
ansible 2.4.0.0
  config file = /home/user/spark/ansible.cfg
  configured module search path = [u'/home/user/spark/library/ansible-aur']
  ansible python module location = /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ansible
  executable location = /usr/bin/ansible
  python version = 2.7.14 (default, Sep 20 2017, 01:25:59) [GCC 7.2.0]
```

Ansible aur:

```
[submodule "library/ansible-aur"]
    path = library/ansible-aur
    url = https://github.com/pigmonkey/ansible-aur.git
```

ansible.cfg

```
[defaults]
library = ./library/ansible-aur
```

**UPD**. If I remove `group` keyword like this:

```
  - name: Create user group
    tags:
      - user
```

I catch an error: unexpected parameter type in action:  after I leave only name and tags. Full error log: pastiebin.com/59cb5b2996a10

Comment: Search your disk for `tags.py` file. If it's in the paths in which Ansible looks for modules, it likely causes such behaviour.

Comment: I have `/usr/lib/calibre/calibre/ebooks/lrf/tags.py`. I tried to uninstall Calibre but it didn't help :(

Comment: I don't think Ansible looks there. What happens if you comment out the `group`-line and leave `tags`? Does it complain about no action being defined?

Comment: @techraf, now it is `exception: unexpected parameter type in action: <class 'ansible.parsing.yaml.objects.AnsibleSequence'>` after I leave only `name` and `tags`. Full error log: https://www.pastiebin.com/59cb5b2996a10

Comment: So the message is different than if you change `tags` to `taggggggs`, right?

Comment: @techraf, yes if it is `tagggggs` error is `no action detected in task`

Comment: So your Ansible is convinced such action module exists. Back to `tags` only - any useful information running with `-vvv`?

Comment: @techraf error logs as before and `ansible version` information mentioned before. No more :(

Comment: What if you switch to a different venv with a clean Ansible?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155401/discussion-between-petrushka-and-techraf).

Comment: @techraf, can `tags` keyword be redefined somewhere else? I mean not in `tags.py`?

Comment: This is [the line](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/devel/lib/ansible/parsing/mod_args.py#L292) with the condition. `module_loader` and `action_loader` are created dynamically with modules found in paths. I can't see any other possibility. Vanilla Ansible does not have this problem. For me it looks like a problem on your machine only.

Comment: @techraf, I've found cause. If you are still interesting please look at answer. Thanks for your useful comments!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's pretty funny story.

I have vim plugin that creates ctags `tags` for a project. And it created file named: `spark/library/ansible-aur/tags`.

It wasn't python file or something. It was just common ctags file.

I found that it was the root of all troubles by using pdb debugger with ansible code.

I've found one of error strings I saw: `conflicting action statements` in ansible code:

```
> /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ansible/parsing/mod_args.py(293)parse()
-> raise AnsibleParserError("conflicting action statements: %s, %s" % (action, item), obj=self._task_ds)
```

And injected `pdb.set_trace()` there.

Then I make some study:

```
(Pdb) item
u'tags'
(Pdb) item in module_loader
True
(Pdb) module_loader.find_plugin(item)
u'/home/user/spark/library/ansible-aur/tags'
```

Last line was kind of hint. After deleting that `tags` file everything was completely ok.

Corresponding bug report: https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/31070